# Power BI Licensig for service Principal

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azure-service-principal

Currently I am trying to embed power BI into a sample web application and I have a pro license. Do I need any other license to embed the report into the application like Premiui or PowerBI Embedded license.

Comment: It depends on how you embed it.

Comment: Currently I have a pro license and I am trying to implement it from Azure Portal by creating a service principal. My concern is how power BI embed license is different from pro and in what case I need a premium license.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, based on my research, the answer to your question is no; you do not need any additional licensing beyond the Power BI Pro account to create and publish content.

But wait, there's more...

Depending on your application, there is a chance you might need to add Power BI Premium, Power BI Premium Gen2, or Power BI Premium Per User. Unfortunately, you need to roll up your sleeves, grab a cup of coffee and spend the next several hours thoroughly reviewing the options. I strongly encourage you to create a "what-if" spreadsheet to run through different scenarios.

Best of luck!